# Storing derived data in the state

Tags: reactjs, flux

Is it a good idea to store derived data in the state in React? The reason I'm looking to do this is to ensure that re-renders occur when the source data set changes.

One example I have with Flux;

```js
class ProductList extends React.PureComponent {
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.props.flux.store('ProductStore').on('change', this.getStateFromFlux);
        this.props.flux.store('ProductAvailabilityStore').on('change', this.getStateFromFlux);
    }

    componentWillUnmount = () => {
        this.props.flux.store('ProductStore').off('change', this.getStateFromFlux);
        this.props.flux.store('ProductAvailabilityStore').off('change', this.getStateFromFlux);
    }

    getStateFromFlux = () => this.setState({ products: this.props.flux.store('ProductStore').getProducts() })

    _isAvailable = product => this.props.flux.store('ProductAvailabilityStore').isAvailable(product.id);

    render = () => this.state.products.map(product => (
        <Product available={this._isAvailable(product)} product={product} />
    ))
}
```

In this case, product availability changing *won't* cause a re-render, which is not what I want.

Now I could do something like this;

```js
class ProductList extends React.PureComponent {
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.props.flux.store('ProductStore').on('change', this.getStateFromFlux);
        this.props.flux.store('ProductAvailabilityStore').on('change', this.getStateFromFlux);
    }

    componentWillUnmount = () => {
        this.props.flux.store('ProductStore').off('change', this.getStateFromFlux);
        this.props.flux.store('ProductAvailabilityStore').off('change', this.getStateFromFlux);
    }

    getStateFromFlux = () => this.setState({
        products: this.props.flux.store('ProductStore').getProducts().map(product => ({
            ...product,
            available: this._isAvailable(product),
        })),
    })

    _isAvailable = product => this.props.flux.store('ProductAvailabilityStore').isAvailable(product.id);

    render = () => this.state.products.map(product => (
        <Product available={this._isAvailable(product)} product={product} />
    ))
}
```

However, that means that any time the availability store changes, we re-render (caused by shallow inequality of the derived state). This happens even if the availability of none of our products have changed.

Now I *could* implement a custom `shouldComponentUpdate` with something like `_.isEqual`, however I feel like this isn't the correct way to do this, or an efficient way at that.

Is there a correct way of handling this? One way I can think of would to be store the list of available products in the state, however that moves the `isAvailable` logic out of the store and into my component, which is something I don't really want to do.
        ))
    }

Comment: Tip: Never forget to include `key` prop when using map function.

Comment: Oops! Thankfully I just wrote these components for this example, and I'm not actually using them like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One posible solution is to move `isAvailable` logic to your `Product` component. Something like this:

```
class ProductList extends React.PureComponent {
    getStateFromFlux = () => this.setState({
        available: this.props.flux.store('ProductAvailabilityStore').isAvailable(this.props.product.id)
    })
}
```

This way, if availability changes, it will call `setState` in your `Product` component only (re-rending itself), instead of rerendering everything.

Comment: My product component is currently a presentation component and I'd prefer to avoid connecting it to Flux if at all possible.